# Sound on particle collision

Tags: particles, audio

Using Blender 2.81, I have a scene with:

1. A cube "template" for particles
2. A plane that emits the above cubes via "Particle Emitter"
3. a plane with "Collision" modifier.

So the particles bounce off the plane rather than passing through it.

How can I either:

1. Add a sound to be played on each particle+plane collision?  or
2. Tell Blender to generate a list of either "time,position,relativeVelocity" or "time,distanceFromCamera,relativeVelocity" data for collisions, so I can generate the sound elsewhere?